# New Emulator Launching repeatedly whenever I run my application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

### I have a problem using emulator in my android project

- **IDE i am using**: `ECLIPSE`
- **I am using**: `API-14`

**Nature of my error**:

- Everytime i run my project that is having a min `sdk-14`  a new
  emulator starts up and project is also not loaded to emulator
- This keeps happening again & again

**Note**: I am not having this problem in `API 8`

Any Solution, Thanks!!

Comment: Did you check the "Use same device for this project" for your app?

Comment: Which one are you refering to .... as i know there r two options ....1)Always prompt to pick device .... 2) Automatically pick compatible device ........ I have selected the second one !

Comment: thats it - you made your choice for that api+project pair. Use run configurations to "uncheck" it

Answer (score 0):

By default, Android run configurations use an "automatic target" mode for selecting a device target. For information on how automatic target mode selects a deployment target, see Automatic and manual target modes below.

Check:
1. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html#RunConfig
2. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html#AutoAndManualTargetModes

You will be having the suitable emulator(which is automatically selected) for API 8 so not facing that problem in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

Right-click project -> Project Properties -> select current -> Edit -> Target tab -> Choose whatever fits you.

I prefer "Always promt to pick device"